# Asp.Net core DropDownListFor - get multiple model properties

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, dropdownlistfor

I am new to ASP.Net MVC and stuck with this issue.
I have done stack overflow search and got some old solutions and one which almost worked, but seems to me not a good solution.
I have the following in View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ProjectTypeId, new SelectList(Model.Projects, "Id", "Name"), "Select Project", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Project Model

```
 public class Project
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public int TaskRate { get; set; }

        public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    }
```

The view generated is:

```
<select class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Project Types field is required." id="ProjectTypeId" name="ProjectTypeId"><option value="">Select Project</option>
<option selected="selected" value="2">Tasks</option>
<option value="3">Search</option>
</select>
```

I wanted the  elements to also have a data-rate attribute like:

```
<select class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Project Types field is required." id="ProjectTypeId" name="ProjectTypeId"><option value="">Select Project</option>
<option selected="selected" value="2" data-rate="5">Tasks</option>
<option value="3" data-rate="6">Search</option>
</select>
```

I have tried doing this way:

```
    <select id="ProjectTypeId" name="ProjectTypeId" class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Project Types field is required.">
        <option value="">Select Project</option>
        @foreach (var type in Model.Projects)
        {
            <option value="@type.Id" data-rate="@type.TaskRate"
                    selected="@((Model.ProjectTypeId == type.Id) ? "selected" : null)">
                @type.Name
            </option>
        }
    </select>
```

But its becomes too messy with the Selected Item attribute, as it does not get selected by default.

Is there a cleaner way to do this please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it by using below code:

```
   <select id="ProjectTypeDD" name="@Html.NameFor(x => x.ProjectTypeId)" class="form-control" data-val-required="The Project Types field is required.">
    <option value="">Select Project</option>
    @foreach (var project in Model.Projects)
    {
        <option value="@project.Id" data-rate="@project.TaskRate"
                selected="@((Model.ProjectTypeId == project.Id) ? "selected" : null)">
            @project.Name
        </option>
    }
</select>
```